# Find the sum of the digits of a number in Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I've come up with a solution for a Euler Problem

```
public class Problem16{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(DecomposeNumber(PowerDigitSum(1000)));
    }// end main

    public static double PowerDigitSum(double iExposant){
        return Math.pow(2, iExposant);
    }// end PowerDigitSum()

    public static int DecomposeNumber(double iNb){
        int[] intTab = String.valueOf(iNb).chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).toArray();
        int iMax = intTab.length;
        int sum = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < iMax; i++){
                sum += intTab[i];
            }
            return sum + 1;
    }// end DecomposeNumber()

}// end classe
```

What I don't understand is my solution works for small numbers such as n^15 but not n^1000 for example, I understand it doesn't work because the number isn't a full set of digits but is there a way to convert let's say 1.071509e+301 into full digits?

Comment: Hint: Here is how to get the digit of a number: int digitValue = (int) (number / Math.pow(10, digitOffset) % 10), where digitOffset is zero-based from the right.

Answer (score 2):

If I got your question right, you want to print a big double without scientific notation. you can do that using `String.format()`.

```
String stringNumber = String.format("%f", iNb);
```

Comment: Nice and exact!

Answer (score 2):

While the other answer certainly solves a part of your problem. I don't recommend using the `double` type for a computation as such of `2 ^ 1000`.

The answer to your problem is to utilise [**`BigInteger`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). As a hint, I will provide the logic for the `PowerDigitSum` method and I'll leave the rest of the logic as an exercise as you're trying to learn from it.

The function `PowerDigitSum` now becomes:

```
public static BigInteger powerDigitSum(int exponent){
      return BigInteger.TWO.pow(exponent); // 2 ^ exponent
}
```

Note, if you're going to proceed with this approach (which I hope you do) then after the call to `map` in the stream pipeline inside the `DecomposeNumber` method, you can simply call `.sum()` and return the result instead of `toArray()`, this means you don't need to perform the subsequent loop to sum the digits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation using BigInteger and no string conversions. As it turns out, modulo of large double values is no better than the string approach.

Note that this is actually the basis of a string conversion, without the overhead that isn't needed in this case.

```
int sumDigits(BigInteger number) {
    int sum = 0;

    while (number.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0) {
        sum += number.mod(BigInteger.TEN).intValue();
        number = number.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
    }

    return sum;
}
```